# Gearman: Restrict workers from picking jobs based on some input params

Tags: php, queue, jobs, gearman

I've a Gearman queue which processes some user specific  data via multiple workers. I do not want a particular user to occupy more than a single worker at once.

Say I've a queue named process_user_data() and I run 4 workers W1, W2, W3, W4
When Userid 1 submits 10 jobs, I want only W1 to process it. W2-W4 should not pick the jobs.

Is this do able in gearman?

Comment: I am still looking for an answer to this. Since this question was submitted long back, is there a way currently to do this in gearman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Gearman does not support this natively. I believe the easiest way would be to prefix / suffix the functions to indicate the user they belong to. E.g: user 1 job should be submitted to `process_data_1()`, and worker 1 would hook up on that instead of a generic `process_data()`. Internally, the workers could still have the same code base, as it would be only a matter of the hook to the Gearman server (which you could manage when launching the worker via a command line parameter):

```
class Worker

public function __construct() {
 $this->user = argv[1];
 $this->worker = new GearmanWorker();
 $this->worker->addServer();
 $this->worker->addFunction("process_data_" . $this->user, array($this, 'process_data'));
}

public function process_data() {
 //work code
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution would work but appears to be a workaround. I would look around for other queue servers. Can you suggest a queue which has persistence and has job type based filtering?

Comment: I don't have much experience with other queues, unfortunately. Beanstalkd has "tubes" that could be allocated to users / workers, but to me that's just a fancy way of handling queues. RabbitMQ has "route keys" that might fit your purpose, but I have never work with them, so I am not 100% sure.

Comment: As @Aurimas suggests, route keys in RabbitMQ would allow what you're asking, and you may wild card the matching keys as well. I wouldn't be too quick to skip his / her suggestion anyway, it might seem like a hack, but it'd work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if the workers are on different servers - just don't declare them with `GearmanClient->addServer()` in your client. If there're on the same server, I suppose you could have several instances of gearmand running on a single machine, on a range of ports. You could then use `addServer(host, port)` to selectively declare which 'groups' should stand a chance of being offered the job/task you're just about to add.

If that's too messy for you, then you may need to choose a different queueing system. I seem to remember reading the Gearman doesn't allow for job-type based filtering, though I'm afraid I don't have a reference for that. Maybe look at RabbitMQ or BeanStalk?